# inserting data to wamp server from android

Tags: java, php, android, database, wamp

i am trying to enter data to my database through wamp server from android. since some parameters like namevaluepair or http client are not working in newer api version of android, i am using target version 21 of api. i am trying to log the coordinates to the database,but whatever value may it be an integer is not getting stored in it.though i am getting message of "data has been successfuly updated".please help me through these. here are my php and java file.

**php file-**

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost ','root','');
mysqli_select_db("tracer1",$con);

$latlong=$_POST['latlong'];


mysqli_query("insert into tracecoordinate2(latlong)values('{$latlong}')");

?>
```

**HERE IS MY JAVA  FILE FROMM ANDROID**

```
package aditya.com.databaseintegration;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static aditya.com.databaseintegration.R.id.textView;

/**
 * Code to demonstrate the insertion of data into android application.
 * Also demonstrates how to retrieve the data.
 * Uses the localhost for local server.
 * Php scripting language for backend integration.
 */

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText etlatlong;
    private Button b;

    Button bSubmit;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener listener;
    public static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/tracer.php";
    String latlong;
    InputStream is = null;
    String exceptionMessage = "There seems to be some problem connecting to database. " +
            "Please check your Internet Connection and try again.";
    String successMessage = "Data has been entered successfully";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy threadPolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(threadPolicy);

        etlatlong = (EditText) findViewById(textView);

        bSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                etlatlong.append("\n " + location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLatitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };

        configure_button();


        bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {

                                          String latlong= etlatlong.getText().toString();


                                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                                           nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latlong", latlong));


                                           try {
                                               HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                               HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                                               httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList));
                                               HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                                               HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                                               is = httpEntity.getContent();
                                               etlatlong.setText("");

                                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), successMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                               is.close();
                                           } catch (IOException e) {
                                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exceptionMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }
        );
    }



    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case 10:
                configure_button();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    void configure_button(){
        // first check for permissions

        // this code won't execute IF permissions are not allowed, because in the line above there is return statement.
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //noinspection MissingPermission
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, listener);
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        else if( id == R.id.action_retrieve_data){
            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RetrieveData.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: first: check, if your android code posts content -> `<?php if(isset($_POST)) { file_put_contents("dump.txt", print_r($_POST, true)); } ?>`

Comment: `trying to enter data to my database`. Can be. But android will communicate with php to begin with. So first check if you can send your data corect to php. And first let php just echo() the received parameters back so you know that all went ok. If all goes ok you could let php communicate with the database. Php can report back to android then.

Comment: you should consider using volley or any other library that is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

thank you :) i finally figured out when i tried to send post through POSTMAN (chrome web store) where data was not being stored. but then the problem i figured was the whole folder of database needed to be stored in www folder (c/wamp64/www)